# Adding sharethis buttons to chrome extension popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sharethis

I'm trying to add the sharethis buttons to popup.html and the following errors appear:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.sharethis.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-9kQ6Bjy+HAjxIkWKadVLttYAH2WuOVEKCHY7pnlgMz0='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

This is my conf: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.sharethis.com; object-src 'self'"`

has anyone managed to get those buttons appear?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unsafe-eval` is used for relaxing `eval` functions, like `setTimeout(String)`, `setInterval(String)` and `new Function(String)`.

`unsafe-inline` would have no effect, according to Official Guide,

> Up until Chrome 45, there was no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, **setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect**.

And for Chrome > 46,

> inline scripts can be whitelisted by **specifying the base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy**. This hash must be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). See [Hash usage for  elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage) for an example.

Comment: thanks, so is there a way to use the sharethis buttons in popup.html?

Comment: @DjangoPy, yes, see hash usage for elements

Comment: has anyone used the sharethis widget on chrome extension before?